# upload file from javascript to rails server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, marionette

I want to upload an image to my Rails server (my front end uses Marionette.js).

It seems extremely simple, however I could not find any straightforward solution. There is [a list of different solutions](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki#ruby), but they all use third-party libraries and require complex workarounds. Is there no easy solution to achieve something as simple as this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with a simple XMLHttpRequest. You can review the sample code form [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) here:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.txt", true);
oReq.send();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of X-origin policy. The response is `XMLHttpRequest cannot load... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`